# SQL: Is the newly selected temp table in FROM clause not passed to the sub-query in WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql

here's a question I'm in trouble with. Basically, there are originally two tables: "a" and "b". I firstly "joined" (without using JOIN clause) them together with some conditions: "a.id=b.id", "b.class="xxx"". **Then I name that temp table as A**, and want to select the data with the highest income within the people in A.

The error returns "the relation A doesn't exist." And the error arrow turns to the clause "select max(A.income) from A". Therefore, **I suspect that the temp table A created in FROM clause will not be passed to the sub-query in WHERE clause?**

```
select * from
(select * from a,b where a.id=b.id and b.class='xxx') as A
where A.income = all
(select max(A.income) from A)
```

I've encountered this problem while using Postgres, but I think it may also happen in other languages like MYSQL or MSSQL. **Are there any possible solutions** to solve that? Without using WITH clause? Thanks. (The reason why I say "sub-query" instead of "query" is because I've tried terms like "where A.income>1000" and they all work)

Comment: Note that this isn't a "temp table", it's called a "derived table"

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your alias `a` hides the table with the same name. Use a different alias name.

It is unclear whether you want to select from the original table `a` in the subquery or from the alias. If it is the former, then the above will solve your problem.

If you want to reference the alias in the subquery, you had better use a common table expression:

```
WITH alias_name AS (/* your FROM subquery */)
SELECT ... /* alias_name can be used in a subquery here */
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try the below -

```
select * from a join b on a.id=b.id where b.class='xxx'
    and income = all (select max(income) from a join b on a.id=b.id where b.class='xxx')
```